# How can I identify the countries that you pass through during a route from location A to location B?

Tags: android, dictionary, geolocation

Basically we have two locations and their coordinates, for example we can go from Germany to France. How can I identify that the country will change during the route ? (of course without checking each coordinate from the route).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line of code to identify the country according to your coordinate position, you can use it to check in some interval or according to your feasiblity

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            String countryCode, countryName;
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
                if (geocoder != null) {
                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.getLatitude(), latLng.getLongitude(), 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                countryCode = "";
                countryName = "";
                if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);
                    countryCode = address.getCountryCode();
                    countryName = address.getCountryName();
                }
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String temp) {
                super.onPostExecute(temp);
            }
      }.execute();
```

The another way to get this same as by using the Google Geocode api please read the full overview from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

hope it will help for you